Splunk query for Forwarder Management
Good day,
I am new to Splunk and would like to get the backend query for the Forwarder Management. I am writing creating a dashboard to check all devices picked up in Splunk and check if they have our security tools installed on them.
To check if a device has the splunk forwarder installed I want to get my data from the Forwarder management dashboard which is a default dashboard where you can create server classes and more.
The Clients tab has all the devices that phoned home in the past 30 days and this means they have the forwarder installed.
Is there an easier way to check all devices for security tools? This is what I have so far.
| rest * count=0 splunk_server=local
| table hostname serverClasses.*.stateOnClient
| untable hostname ServerClassNames dummy
| rex field=ServerClassNames "serverClasses\.(?<Azutre_VMS_Security_Tools>[^\.]+)\.stateOnClient$"
| stats values(ServerClassNames) as ServerClassNames dc(ServerClassNames) as NumberOfServerClasses by hostname
| rename hostname as clientName
| table clientName, NumberOfServerClasses, ServerClassNames

This is my code to get all devices
index=* earliest=-30d latest=now
| stats dc(host) as UniqueHostCount by host
| where UniqueHostCount > 0
| table host

I want to get the query first for the forwarder( it does not work the one above) before querying if the host does not display in the forwarder to display in the results

I have also noticed that I cannot distinct by only the hostname as some devices will have WSL2 on it which will create 2 instances of the same host

There are a few ways to find which devices are sending data to Splunk.
To get a list of forwarders, send a /services/deployment/server/clients API request to the Deployment Server.  See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.2.2/RESTREF/RESTdeploy#deployment.2Fserver.2Fclients for details.
Another way to find forwarders is to search the internal index for incoming TCP connections.
index=_internal sourcetype=splunkd component=Metrics group=tcpin_connections 
| dedup sourceHost 
| table sourceHost fwdType 

To see all hosts that send data, not just forwarders, count the hosts found in all indexes.
| tstats count where index=* host=* by host

